# find the redirected url using curl

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to find the redirected url from a source url to get this I am using the following code...

```
$url="http://www.idealo.fr/go/737821809.html?categoryId=12313&pos=1&price=499.99&productid=4716350&sid=26246&type=offer";
$ch = curl_init();
        $timeout = 0;
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);

      $header = curl_exec($ch);
        $retVal = array();
        $fields = explode("\r\n", preg_replace_callback ('/\x0D\x0A[\x09\x20]+/', ' ', $header));
        foreach( $fields as $field ) {
            if( preg_match('/([^:]+): (.+)/m', $field, $match) ) {
                $match[1] = preg_replace_callback ('/(?<=^|[\x09\x20\x2D])./e', 'strtoupper("\0")', strtolower(trim($match[1])));
                if( isset($retVal[$match[1]]) ) {
                    $retVal[$match[1]] = array($retVal[$match[1]], $match[2]);
                } else {
                    $retVal[$match[1]] = trim($match[2]);
                }
            }
        }
echo '<pre>';
print_r($retVal);
echo '</pre>';

if (isset($retVal['Location'])){
     echo $retVal['Location'];
} else {

     echo $_GET[$urlKey];
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Now, it returns me the following output...

```
 Array (
     [date] => Tue, 06 Sep 2016 15:34:27 GMT
     [server] => idealoAppServer
     [location] => http://track.effiliation.com/servlet/effi.redir?id_compteur=13087834&url=http://www.priceminister.com/offer/buy/1134677256/canon-eos-750d-appareil-photo-numerique.html

     [content-type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
     [content-length] => 0
     [set-cookie] => Array
         (
             [0] => Array
                 (
                     [0] => oop_mvp_2=A; domain=.idealo.fr; path=/; expires=Thu, 05-Dec-2016 15:34:27 GMT
                     [1] => ipcuid=01jo0lb800isrmzsx0; domain=.idealo.fr; path=/; expires=Mon, 27-Aug-2018 15:34:27 GMT
                 )

             [1] => icda=1; domain=.idealo.fr; path=/; expires=Wed, 06-Sep-2017 15:34:27 GMT
         )

     [vary] => Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
     [connection] => close )
```

Now, from this array I just need the following output...

```
http://www.priceminister.com/offer/buy/1134677256/canon-eos-750d-appareil-photo-numerique.html
```

Can anyone please help me to form the array so that I just get the url only...I have recently upgraded to php7 from php 5...is that may be one of the reason...

Comment: You don't have valid callbacks on your `preg_replace_callback()` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `parse_url` to parse the url you receive in `location` key

```
$url_parse = parse_url($retVal['location']);
```

After that you will have somehing like this in `$url_parse`:

```
array (
  'scheme' => 'http',
  'host' => 'track.effiliation.com',
  'path' => '/servlet/effi.redir',
  'query' => 'id_compteur=13087834&url=http://www.priceminister.com/offer/buy/1134677256/canon-eos-750d-appareil-photo-numerique.html',
)
```

So the query is in `query` key. Now we need to parse it and you cna use `parse_str`

```
parse_str($url_parse['query'], $output);
```

And now in `$output` you will have something like this:

```
array (
  'id_compteur' => '13087834',
  'url' => 'http://www.priceminister.com/offer/buy/1134677256/canon-eos-750d-appareil-photo-numerique.html',
)
```

So the url that you want is in `$output['url']`

```
echo $output['url']; //here is the url that you want.
```